# Upgrade tailwind v2 to v3 TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, upgrade, tailwind-css

I have follow the guide to upgrade on tailwind https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide.

But I know get an error on my ionic angular app

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '700' of undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the version of the tailwind plugins I had was not compatible with Tailwind v3

I had to update theme, tailwind typography and forms in my case.

```
npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography@latest \
@tailwindcss/forms@latest
```

Comment: Don't forget forms also!: 'npm i @tailwindcss/forms@latest' Source: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/6398